# Disable button based on text input

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have 2 fields, email and password and a button:

The button is disabled based on `password.length`, but I also want it to be disabled based on valid email address.

I tried doing:

Template:

```
<v-btn
 class="btn white--text"
 :disabled="password.length <= 6 && isValidEmail"
 @click="onSignIn"
 >Sign In</v-btn>
```

Script:

```
computed: {
    isValidEmail() {
      return validateEmail(this.email);
    },
  },
```

But it doesn't work, only password.length works.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Found how to do it, Like [Liel Fridman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11143111/liel-fridman) said you need simple expressions in v-bind( no `&& ||`):

```
  computed: {
    isValidForm() {
      return (this.password.length > 6 && validateEmail(this.email));
    },
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another computed property and use that. Only simple expressions work inside v-bind

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how to do what you suggested.
How will using another computed property work differently?

Comment: I think the and expression may not work inside v-bind, and if that is the case, then using another computed property will solve that problem

Answer (score 0):

```
I think you should use OR instead of && operator, so whenever one of the condition return false, its disabled

  <v-btn
  class="btn white--text"
  :disabled="password.length <= 6 || !isValidEmail"
  @click="onSignIn"
  >Sign In</v-btn>
```

Comment: doesn't work.
and isValidEmail is a function that returns true or false, so no need for the exclamation mark.

Answer (score 0):

you can use direct bind data :
:disabled="password.length <= 10